# find input tag inside a html div and that div is stored in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating fully flexible contact us form where user can drag and drop input elements.
so in that case I am stuck in a problem

the html structure is:

```
<div class="ns_field_box">
    <input type="text" data-name="checkbox_label" class="nsdummy-label" value="CheckBox">
    <span class="nscheckbox"></span> <input type="text" data-name="checkbox_desc" value="Add checkbox description">
    <div class="nshandle">
        <span class="dashicons dashicons-move"></span>
        <span class="dashicons dashicons-trash nsremove_feild"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I stored `<div class="ns_field_box">` this element in a javascript variable and want to find and store all input elements inside this variable

javascript code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_form', function () {
    var allelems = $('#B .ns_field_box');
    for (i = 0; i < allelems.length; i++) {
        var elem = allelems[i];
        console.log(elem.children('input')); // at this line browser console says 
                                             // 'elem.children is not a function'
    }
})
```

Required files are already set in a proper order

```
// jquery file
<script src='https://siga.local/nitin/plugins/wp-content/plugins/ns-contact-form/inc/assets/js/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='ns_cf_jquery-js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='ns_cf_sortablejs-js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js?ver=1.14.0' id='ns_cf_jquerysortablejs-js'></script>
// main javascript file where the code I wrote
<script src='https://siga.local/nitin/plugins/wp-content/plugins/ns-contact-form/inc/assets/js/main.js?ver=1.0.0' id='ns_cf_js-js'></script>
```

and the browsers javascript console says

```
main.js?ver=1.0.0:34 Uncaught TypeError: 
    elem.children is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js?ver=1.0.0:34)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
```

Thank you to all who help me in advance

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, have you considered `.find()`? [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: the indexes in a jquery object are normal Elements, not jQuery objects. Use `.each()` to loop through your jquery object instead of a manual loop :)

Comment: @DBS  I have already tried all possible methods built in jQuery

Comment: @Sysix I tried .each() with find() and children() but the same problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jqueryCollection[i]` returns a DOM object, but you're trying to use a jquery's children() method.

One solution is to change to

```
var elem = $(allelems[i]);
```

to keep `elem` as a jquery object.

You can make your code more succinct with the use of jquery's `.each` and using

```
var elem = $(this);
```

to ensure `elem` continues on as a jquery object with all of jquery's methods.

You snippet would be updated to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_form', function () {
    var allelems = $('#B .ns_field_box');
    allelems.each(function() { 
        var elem = $(this);
        console.log(elem.children('input').length); 
    }
})
```

Comment: the problem occurs because I didn't know the difference between JavaScript DOM and jQuery object. the concept is noted! thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('click', '#submit_form', function () {

                var allelems = $('#B .ns_field_box');
                for (i = 0; i < allelems.length; i++) {
                    var elem = $(allelems[i]);
                    console.log(elem.children('input'));                    
                }
            })
```